# Pull min values from dataframe without repeating values in other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (`df`) with 16 rows and 3 columns:

```
Var1           Var2          value
1.060579189    1.018186563   0.042392626
0.020169078    0.119923679  -0.099754601
1.704759781    1.427241887   0.277517894
1.060579189    1.427241887  -0.366662698
1.060579189    0.636595019   0.42398417
-0.415685797   0.119923679  -0.535609476
0.020169078    0.636595019  -0.61642594
1.704759781    1.018186563   0.686573218
1.060579189    0.119923679   0.94065551
0.020169078    1.018186563  -0.998017484
-0.415685797   0.636595019  -1.052280816
1.704759781    0.636595019   1.068164762
0.020169078    1.427241887  -1.407072808
-0.415685797   1.018186563  -1.43387236
1.704759781    0.119923679   1.584836102
-0.415685797   1.427241887  -1.842927684
```

The `value` column is just `Var1`-`Var2` sorted by absolute value. I would like to be able to pull the minimum values in the `value` column on the basis that no values are repeated from either of the first two columns (i.e., the minimum value of `value` for each unique pair of `Var1` and `Var2`). In this example, there would be four values pulled: `0.042392626, -0.099754601, 0.277517894, -1.052280816`. This is because `df[2,4]` is a repeat of `df[2,3]`, but because `df[2,3]` came first, that is the value that is pulled. Additionally, we have to skip the `df[11,3]` for the last value because it is the only unique pair left.

Is there an easy way to do this iteratively over the columns and rows of the dataframe? It would make life much easier when I expand this to more complex, longer dataframes.

**UPDATE**

I managed to hack this together with some trial and error:

```
fin <- df[1,]
for (k in 1:nrow(df)) {
  n <- k+1
  if(df[n,1] %in% fin[,'Var1']){
    next
  }
  if(df[n,2] %in% fin[,"Var2"]){
    next
  } else {
    fin[n,] <- df[n,]
  }
}
```

It certainly isn't the most pretty, and if anyone has any more elegant solutions I'd be happy to hear them and learn something new!

Comment: `0.42398417` in 5th row of `Var1` is duplicate of its value in 4th row. How is it selected?

Comment: Damn, you're right. The fourth value would actually be `-1.052280816`, thus making the problem more complicated than I thought. This is because every value besides `-0.415685797` & `0.636595019` had been paired up before, and that is the only unique pair left. I will update the question accordingly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Naa..I think even for `-1.052280816` values in `Var1` and `Var2` repeated. See 6th and 7th row respectively.

Comment: FYI `df[row, column]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this below. This would pull the 2 lowest values from `value` such that repeats of `Var1` and `Var2` are ignored.

`head(sort(df[!duplicated(df$Var1) & !duplicated(df$Var2),'value']),2)`